How can I cap video length to just slightly below 60 seconds without re-encoding with FFmpeg?
I'm currently making a script to cap my videos at just slightly below 60 seconds. So if I have a video clip that is exactly 60 seconds long, I trim it by exactly 1 frame so it is slightly below 60 seconds like 59.99. If I have a video that is more than 60 seconds I first cap it using this bash script:
#!/bin/bash

input_video="$1"
output_dir="$(dirname "$input_video")"
output_video="${output_dir}/$(basename "$input_video" .mp4)-capped-60-seconds.mp4"
duration=$(ffmpeg -i "$input_video" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Duration: )[^,]+' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
echo "Video duration: $duration seconds"
ffmpeg -i "$input_video" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:00 -c copy "${output_dir}/temp_60sec.mp4"
new_duration=$(ffmpeg -i "${output_dir}/temp_60sec.mp4" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Duration: )[^,]+' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
echo "New trimmed video duration: $new_duration"

But this does not seem to work. If I have a video that is duration = 60.09 it does not get capped at 60 seconds. The new_duration is still the same as the original 60.09. How can I achieve trimming that will always make a video length just slightly below 60 seconds? This is the full script I'm currently using which only works sometimes. Is this even possible without re-encoding?
#!/bin/bash

input_video="$1"
output_dir="$(dirname "$input_video")"
output_video="${output_dir}/$(basename "$input_video" .mp4)-capped-60-seconds.mp4"

duration=$(ffmpeg -i "$input_video" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Duration: )[^,]+' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')

if (( $(echo "$duration < 60" | bc -l) )); then
    echo "Video is less than 60 seconds, no action needed."
    exit 0
fi

echo "Video duration: $duration seconds"

frame_rate=$(ffmpeg -i "$input_video" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=, )\d+(\.\d+)? fps' | grep -oP '\d+(\.\d+)?')
echo "Frame rate: $frame_rate fps"

frame_duration=$(echo "scale=6; 1 / $frame_rate" | bc)
echo "Duration of one frame: $frame_duration seconds"

ffmpeg -i "$input_video" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:01:00 -c copy "${output_dir}/temp_60sec.mp4"

new_duration=$(echo "scale=6; 60 - $frame_duration" | bc)
echo "New duration: $new_duration seconds"

ffmpeg -i "${output_dir}/temp_60sec.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to "$new_duration" -c copy "$output_video"

rm "${output_dir}/temp_60sec.mp4"

new_duration=$(ffmpeg -i "$output_video" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Duration: )[^,]+' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
echo "New trimmed video duration: $new_duration"
mv $output_video $input_video
echo "Final video saved overwritten to: $input_video"


Use ffprobe, not ffmpeg to fetch information about a file. The readout in the latter is rounded and meant for convenience. Use ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries format=duration -i INPUT

@Gyan cool thanks for this info. I'll use this command for getting duration so now I get a more accurate output 60.095. Do you know how I can then cap the video length to just slightly below 60 seconds like 1 frame below 60 seconds without re-encoding? Or is it impossible without re-encoding?
